# Modal not getting data in option tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js

I'm trying to use the Modal feature from Bootstrap 3 to show Product option. It works in .js file when I checked using console.log, but it is not working at HTML side.

Here's my code:

Of HTML

```
<div id="moveProdModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h3 id="myModalLabel" data-i18n="moveProducts">Move Products</h3> 
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body"> <input id="mg"> <%= brands %></input>
    <fieldset>

        <label style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold" data-i18n="askBrand">Which Collection would you like to move the selected Digital Interaction to?</label>  
          <% if(brands){ %>    
             <select class="brand" id="brand" style="margin-left:107px;width:314px">

              <% for(var i=0; i<brands.length; i++){ %>
                  <% if(i==0) {%>
                    <option value="<%= brands[i]._id %>" selected><%= brands[i].name %></option>
                  <% } else { %>
                    <option value="<%= brands[i]._id %>"><%= brands[i].name %></option>
                  <% } %>

              <% } %>   
            </select>         
          <%  } %>

          <% } %>


        <div style="border-style: dotted;color: rgb(241, 233, 233);margin-left:107px;margin-right:107px;padding-top:13px;padding-bottom:13px">
          <label class="control-label"><span data-i18n="confirmMove1" style="color:red;padding-left:9px">Are you sure you would like to move this/these</span><label data-i18n="confirmMove2" style="color:red;text-align:center;">to the selected Collection?</label></label>
        </div>

    </fieldset>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn cancelDelete1 btn-danger customButton" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" data-i18n="cancel">Cancel</button>
    <button class="btn moveProduct btn-success customButton" data-id="single" data-i18n="move">Move</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS code:
I am getting brands from another function using ajax call and it is getting fetched.

```
"click #move-product":"loadModel2",
loadModel2: function(){                    
      $('#moveProdModal').modal('show');
      console.log(brands);
}
```

Comment: If you are calling your function 'loadModal2' inside the Ajax callback, you will need to pass brands as a parameter unless brands is a very global variable. It'd be useful to see that part of the code also

Comment: brands is a global variable.

Comment: I got the solution, to use brands in bootstrap modal in HTML page we have to pass the brands with an id using jquery to bootstrap modal.

Comment: If your question is resolved, it is encouraged that you post an answer and that you mark it as accepted.